# How to determine position of row in sql result-set?

Tags: sql, count

i have a sql query:

```
select id, name from table order by name
```

result looks like this:

```
52 arnold 
33 berta 
34 chris 
47 doris
52 emil
```

for a given id=47 how can i determine the position in the result set?
the result should be 4 because:

```
52 arnold
33 berta
34 chris
```

are before (47, doris) and id=41 is on the 4th position in the result set.

How to do this in SQL? 
How in HQL? 
In a pagination example, do i have to execute 2 statements or is there a solution where i can retrieve exactly that window which contains the row with id=47?

postgreSQL and java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The previous posts are correct. Use ROW_NUMBER if using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or greater.

However, your tags do not specify that you're using MSSQL, so here's a solution that should work across most RDBMS implementations. Essentially, use a correlated subquery to determine the count of rows in the same set that are less than the current row, based on the values of the ORDER clause of the outer query. Something like this:

```
SELECT      T1.id,
            T1.[name],
            (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM table T2 
             WHERE T2.[name] < T1.[name]) + 1 AS rowpos
FROM        table T1
ORDER BY    T1.[name]
```

Comment: I guess that it depends on what you want to use to break the tie. You can add additional crieria to the sub-query to further distinguish the 'rowpos' calculation so that no ties are generated, or add an additional order clause to the outer query to break the tie.

Comment: Isn't this case faster than the ROW_NUMBER solution even if your DB offers ROW_NUMBER? I assume this way is O(n) vs. O(n*log(n)) (getting the row number)

Comment: Perhaps. I would think it all depends on how the vendor implements ROW_NUMBER. For SQL Server it appears that there is documented evidence of performance issues with ROW_NUMBER over large datasets, which would imply that my solution is faster in that situation. See the answer from @Aaronaught [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2309247/49954). I think a lot will be dependent on how a correlated subquery is optimized as well. You would probably have to do your own benchmarking to be certain.

Answer (score 6):

You don't mention which RDBMS you're running, but if you're using SQL Server 2005 or greater, you can employ the ROW_NUMBER() function - like this:

```
SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS RowNumber
FROM   MyTable
```

Then, to fetch a given row, you can use a derived table or a common table expression - like this:

```
;WITH NumberedRows
AS
(SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS RowNumber
FROM    MyTable)
SELECT RowNumber FROM NumberedRows WHERE id = 47
```

To sort out "which page" the record is on, you would need to divide the row number by the number of records per page, and round up to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL 2005, you can use [Row_Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which version of SQL you are using.

If you are using MSSQL 2005 you can use the the new analytical function ROW_NUMBER () which generates the sequential number in order which we define in order by clause. The syntax of ROW_NUMBER () function is:

ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY )

or

ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY )

If you are using an older version of SQL Server you can create a temp table with an identity column and select the results from that.

Answer (score 1):

use Row_Number