# How can I assign a number to each row in a table representing the record number?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-express

How can I show the number of rows in a table in a way that when a new record is added the number representing the row goes higher and when a record is deleted the number gets updated accordingly?
To be more clear,suppose I have a simple table like this :

> ID int (primary key) Name varchar(5)

The ID is set to get incremented by itself (using identity specification) so it can't represent the number of row(record) since if I have for example 3 records as:

> ID   NAME
>    1   Alex
>    2   Scott
>    3   Sara

and I delete Alex and Scott and add a new record it will be:

```
3 Sara
4 Mina
```

So basically I'm looking for a sql-side solution for doing this so that I don't change anything else in the source code in multiple places.

I tried to write something to get the job done but it failes. Here  it is :

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS [row number],Name
FROM          dbo.Test
GROUP BY ID, Name
HAVING        (ID = ID)
```

This shows as:

```
row number            Name
1                     Alex
1                     Scott
1                     Sara
```

while I want it to get shown as:

```
row number            Name
1                     Alex
2                     Scott
3                     Sara
```

Comment: What you tried and where you want to show no of rows?

Comment: i updated the question.I want to show the numbers when i use select commands.so that each time i select the results they have a normal Acending numbering representing records.

Comment: Cant you just show id generated in the row number column? Didnt understood what is use of  count(*)

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079480/how-to-determine-position-of-row-in-sql-result-set/1079602#1079602

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want the number against the rows while selecting the data and not in the database then you can use this

```
select row_number() over(order by id) from dbo.Test
```

This will give the row number n for nth row.

Comment: why do i get "The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported." error ? (got it, i shouldnt run this in the designer :) )

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber
FROM   MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called an auto increment.

For SQL-Server this is achieved by adding the `IDENTITY(1,1)` attribute to the table definition.

Other RDBMS use a different syntax. Firebird for example has generators, which do the counting. In a BEFORE-INSERT trigger you would assign the ID-field to the current value of the generator (which will be increased automatically).

Comment: I know that and i am using it now, the problem with Identity(1,1) is that if i have records aleardy and delete those (suppose ID number 1) and start again i will not get that number 1 as ID again even when there is no records at all !. if i have 3 records as (1 2 3 , and delete number two , they will as (1 3 ) i want to get them to 'show' as ( 1 2 )

Comment: Why would you want that? Ok, suppose you want it, then use a trigger. And a second table which holds the deleted IDs.

Comment: How possibly could i do that?apart form that is it even more reasonable that using row_number() in this scenario?

Comment: Hi, I misunderstood your problem. You want to *show* row numbers and not maintain them in the table. Doing that would drastically increase performance overhead as with each delete, you would have to renumber the table. It is generally not a good idea to have the RDBMS issue row numbers, as this also implies an ordering function.

Comment: Thanks , so what could be a feasible solution in this regard then?

Comment: Use any of the RowNumber() OVER ... solutions they create a view of your data the way you want it.

Comment: Brilliant answer - if you can not use order by for some reason, this is definitely the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem a while ago, but I was using SQL Server 2000, so although row number() is the best solution, in SQL Server 2000, this isn't available.  A workaround for this is to create a temporary table, insert all the values with auto increment, and replace the current table with the new table in T-SQL.