# Entity Framework 6: Calculate numeric-index (position) of row in a given table/set of results

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Essentially the question boils down to "How can one apply the following raw-SQL-fueled approach in EF6?" (is it even possible?):

[How to determine position of row in sql result-set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079480/how-to-determine-position-of-row-in-sql-result-set)

Update: This is *not* what I am looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165249/863651

It doesn't employ ROW_NUMBER or something similar in db-side. It uses linq purely on the C# (aka it fetches all results and then enumerates them yikes!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add ROW\_NUMBER to a LINQ query or Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity)

Answer (score 0):

Well if what you need is an index on every result you can simply do

```
var result = Table.Select((x,i)=> new {val = x, ind = i});
```

This will essentially append the index of each row to its data, if you wanted the index of a particular id in the table you can do something like

```
int index = result.where(x => x.id == [someval]).Select(y => y.ind).First();
```

Where result is the result from the query above ofcourse, note I typed this on my phone the snytax might have a few errors